Cannot call mkfs.hfs after installing hfsutils
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 desktop.
I have already install hfsutils via
sudo apt install hfsutils

But when I invoke it
sudo mkfs.hfs /dev/sdb9

I still get "command not found" error. Why?

You've not told us your release, but https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/amd64/hfsutils/filelist shows what gets installed by your machine for noble (24.04) using amd64 architecture, so it wouldn't be expected. We currently don't know what release/architecture you're using, as you've not told us.

@guiverc, sorry I include the release info, which is the latest version.

If your 'update' actually resolved your issue, please remove that from your question, and instead write it up as your answer. You can then 'accept' that answer (in time) and gain 15 rep etc.

@guiverc, Thank you.

Well done for solving the issue.  :)

I solve the issue. I need to invoke
sudo apt install hfsprogs

instead.
